# Output only function definition after checking

Tags: regex, perl

I have a function name "ChainCtrlBuildChain" as text in a file(FILE).

```
A c file(FILE1) with content

VideoChainT* ChainCtrlBuildChain(ChainCtrlT* pChainCtrl, char* pChainName, ChainDefT* pDef)
            {
          ...
            {
 ModTrace((ModT*) pChainCtrl, "ChainCtrlBuildChain: ERROR, chain init failure [chain: %4.4s inst: %d] [err: %d]\n",
                        ...
            }
```

My code:

```
my @Array=<FILE>;
my @Array1=<FILE1>;

foreach my $text (@Array1){
if (index($text, $Array[0]) !=-1)
{
print "$text \n";
}
}
```

Gives this output:

```
VideoChainT* ChainCtrlBuildChain(ChainCtrlT* pChainCtrl, char* pChainName, ChainDefT* pDef)
ModTrace((ModT*) pChainCtrl, "ChainCtrlBuildChain: ERROR, chain init failure [chain: %4.4s inst: %d] [err: %d]\n",
```

I want this instead:

```
VideoChainT* ChainCtrlBuildChain(ChainCtrlT* pChainCtrl, char* pChainName, ChainDefT* pDef)
```

I have to make it generalized as input files are by users and not fixed.

I was thinking

```
if (index($text, $Array[0]) != -1 && index('**WHAT SHOULD I WRITE SO THAT IT SKIPS ANY ARGUMENTS PRESENT AND JUST CHECKS WHETHER ITS A FUNCTION DEFINITION OR NOT**')!= -1)
```

Comment: You want to match the string only when it's at the beginning of a function definition? You pretty much have to write a C parser to do that.

Comment: Maybe `etags` and `ctags` can give you an inspiration.

Comment: C parser is ok but will it be able to recognize function definition only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case you're content using your function name plus `(` sufficient for a function definition this should work:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use warnings;
use strict;

my $function_file = 'functions.txt';
my $src_file = 'src.c';

open(my $ff,'<',$function_file) or die "Cant open $function_file: $!\n";
open(my $sf,'<',$src_file) or die "Cant open $src_file: $!\n";

my @array = <$ff>;
my @array2 = <$sf>;

close($ff);
close($sf);

foreach my $func (@array){
    chomp $func;
    foreach my $src_line (@array2){
        if ($src_line =~ /$func\(/){
            print $src_line;
        }
    }
}
```

BTW: you'll have less pain in your perl-life if you use 3-arg open!

Comment: Yes. why didn't this come to my mind.It will definitely work just need to exclude constructors and static functions

Comment: will keep that in mind about 3-arg open. i am new to perl and your advice will definitely help me in future.